# Architect blogs and web sites

Tags: architecture, resources

Are there any good blogs or web sites out there for someone with the title architect to check out?

I know of some great development sites, but I am looking stuff specifically related to architecture.

Comment: Architecture (like development) is a fairly broad subject - did you have any specific area in mind?

Answer (score 2):

[Highscalability](http://highscalability.com/) is very good site which provide analysis of real time architectures like Ebay, Google, Facebook and Twitter and it also lists approaches for Architecting Highly Scalable Web Applications, hope this would be a good starting point.

Comment: @Thanks APC, I am big fan of High Scalability

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN Architecture center has a lot of good content, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/default

Answer (score 0):

Here's some material I've found useful, and each has a different area of focus:

- http://www.bredemeyer.com/links.htm
- [Software Engineering Institute, Carnegie Mellon University](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/architecture/tools/)
- [Roger Sessions / ObjectWatch White Papers](http://www.objectwatch.com/white_papers.htm)
- [Evaluating Application Architecture, Quantitatively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/ff476939%28en-us%29.aspx)

As far as blogs are concerned, each tends to focus on a specific subject or aspect of architecture; I must admit there aren't any which I regularly read that I can think of.  I tend to look for content of a specific subject rather than get a daily / weekly dose of architecture from a blog.  It's also worth considering that the pace of change in architecture isn't as rapid as within specific technology stacks (for example).

Another source of useful is some of the architecture forums at places like Linked-In, but I find that the quality of these varies greatly - there's always some really great insightful comments but you often have to wade through a ton of dross first.  Definitely worth checking out though, there's heaps on LinkedIn alone, and each has a distinctive flavour:

- [Architecture in Action Group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Architecture-in-Action-Group-2912001)
- [iCMG Architecture World](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=1976291)
- [Wellington Solution Architects Forum](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=2266264)

Finally, I've written a bit of architectural topics which have interested me, you can find a bunch of PDF's [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2942088AAC497628&id=2942088AAC497628!240) including:

- A Tale of Two Architects - Computer Science vs Civil Engineering
- Architectural Cheat Sheets
- Free Un-Evil Options Analysis Template
- Solutioning vs Solution Architecture
- Hitchhikers Guide to NFRs - the System Quality Attributes Map
- How Not to Screw Up an RFP Response